# how to read from configfile in jenkins pipeline BEFORE stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configfile, which is a JSON file. I want to be able to read it *before* any steps, as it provides variables I need to execute them. However, I don't know where do I put that. To contain `config file provider` call, I tried creating a separate `node`  before `pipeline`, to no avail, also tried to set up `script` in `stages`, `stage` (also as `post`).

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple practice on my jenkins as following.

```
def config;
node(){
    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '<your config file id>', targetLocation: 'myConfig')]) {
        config = readJSON file: 'myConfig'
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {

            steps {
                echo config.myKey // or config['myKey']
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Antek Did this work? If so, can you mark it as answered?

Comment: no, unfortunately not. I gave up eventually and sticked with `environment` and `withCredentials`